# django rest framework - backward serialization to avoid prefetch_related

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-related-manager

I have two models, `Item` and `ItemGroup`:

```
class ItemGroup(models.Model):
   group_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   # fields..

class Item(models.Model):
   item_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   item_group = models.ForeignKey(ItemGroup, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   # other fields..
```

I want to write a serializer that will fetch all item groups with their item list as a nested array.

So I want this output:

```
[ {group_name: "item group name", "items": [... list of items ..] }, ... ]
```

As I see, I should write this with django rest framework:

```
class ItemGroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
      model = ItemGroup
      fields = ('item_set', 'group_name')
```

Means, I have to write a serializer for `ItemGroup` (not for `Item`).
To avoid many queries I pass this queryset:

```
ItemGroup.objects.filter(**filters).prefetch_related('item_set')
```

The problem that I see is, for a large dataset, `prefetch_related` results in an extra query with a VERY large sql `IN` clause, which I could avoid with the query on the Item objects instead:

```
Item.objects.filter(**filters).select_related('item_group')
```

Which results in a JOIN which is way better.

Is it possible to query `Item` instead of `ItemGroup`, and yet to have the same serialization output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start off with the basics

### A serializer can only work with the data it is given

So this means that in order to get a serializer which can serialize a list of `ItemGroup` and `Item` objects in a nested representation, it has to be given that list in the first place. You've accomplished that so far using a query on the `ItemGroup` model that calls `prefetch_related` to get the related `Item` objects. You've also identified that `prefetch_related` triggers a second query to get those related objects, and this isn't satisfactory.

### `prefetch_related` is used to get multiple related objects

What does this mean exactly? When you are querying for a single object, like a single `ItemGroup`, you use `prefetch_related` to get a relationship containing multiple related objects, like a reverse foreign key (one-to-many) or a many-to-many relationship that's been defined. Django intentionally uses a second query to get these objects for a few reasons

1. The join that would be required in a `select_related` is often non-performant when you force it to do a join against a second table. This is because a right outer join would be required in order to ensure that no `ItemGroup` objects that do not contain an `Item` are missed.
2. The query used by `prefetch_related` is an `IN` on an *indexed primary key field*, which is one of the most performant queries out there.
3. The query only requests the IDs of `Item` objects it knows exist, so it can efficiently handle duplicates (in the case of many-to-many relationships) without having to do an additional subquery.

All of this is a way to say: `prefetch_related` is doing exactly what it should do, and it's doing that for a reason.

### But I want to do this with a `select_related` anyway

Alright, alright. That's what was asked for, so let's see what can be done.

There are a few ways to accomplish this, all of which have their pros and cons and none of which work without some manual "stitching" work in the end. I am making the assumption that you aren't using the built-in ViewSet or generic views provided by DRF, but if you are then the stitching must happen in the `filter_queryset` method to allow the built-in filtering to work. Oh, and it probably breaks pagination or makes it almost useless.

### Preserving the original filters

The original set of filters are being applied to the `ItemGroup` object. And since this is being used in an API, these are probably dynamic and you don't want to lose them. So, you are going to need to apply filters through one of two ways:

1. Generate the filters and then prefix them with the related name

   So you would generate your normal `foo=bar` filters and then prefix them before passing it to `filter()` so it'd be `related__foo=bar`. This may have some performance implications since you're now filtering across relationships.
2. Generate the original subquery and then pass it to the `Item` query directly

   This is probably the "cleanest" solution, except you're generating an `IN` query with comparable performance to the `prefetch_related` one. Except it's worse performance, since this is treated as an uncacheable subquery instead.

Implementing both of these are realistically out of the scope of this question, since we want to be able to "flip and stitch" the `Item` and `ItemGroup` objects so the serializer works.

### Flipping the `Item` query so you get a list of `ItemGroup` objects

Taking the query given in the original question, where `select_related` is being used to grab all of the `ItemGroup` objects alongside the `Item` objects, you are returned a queryset full of `Item` objects. We actually want a list of `ItemGroup` objects, since we're working with an `ItemGroupSerializer`, so we're going to have to "flip it" around.

```
from collections import defaultdict

items = Item.objects.filter(**filters).select_related('item_group')

item_groups_to_items = defaultdict(list)
item_groups_by_id = {}

for item in items:
    item_group = item.item_group

    item_groups_by_id[item_group.id] = item_group
    item_group_to_items[item_group.id].append(item)
```

I am intentionally using the `id` of the `ItemGroup` as the key for the dictionaries since most Django models are not immutable, and sometimes people override the hashing method to be something other than the primary key.

This will get you a mapping of `ItemGroup` objects to their related `Item` objects, which is ultimately what you need in order to "stitch" them together again.

### Stitching the `ItemGroup` objects back with their related `Item` objects

This part isn't actually difficult to do, since you have all of the related objects already.

```
for item_group_id, item_group_items in item_group_to_items.items():
    item_group = item_groups_by_id[item_group_id]

    item_group.item_set = item_group_items

item_groups = item_groups_by_id.values()
```

This will get you all of the `ItemGroup` objects that were requested and have them stored as `list` in the `item_groups` variable. Each `ItemGroup` object will have the list of related `Item` objects set in the `item_set` attribute. You may want to rename this so it doesn't conflict with the automatically generated reverse foreign key of the same name.

From here, you can use it as you normally would in your `ItemGroupSerializer` and it should work for serialization.

### Bonus: A generic way to "flip and stitch"

You can make this generic (and unreadable) pretty quickly, for use in other similar scenarios:

```
def flip_and_stitch(itmes, group_from_item, store_in):
    from collections import defaultdict

    item_groups_to_items = defaultdict(list)
    item_groups_by_id = {}

    for item in items:
        item_group = getattr(item, group_from_item)

        item_groups_by_id[item_group.id] = item_group
        item_group_to_items[item_group.id].append(item)

    for item_group_id, item_group_items in item_group_to_items.items():
        item_group = item_groups_by_id[item_group_id]

        setattr(item_group, store_in, item_group_items)

    return item_groups_by_id.values()
```

And you'd just call this as

```
item_groups = flip_and_stitch(items, 'item_group', 'item_set')
```

Where:

- `items` is the queryset of items that you requested originally, with the `select_related` call already applied.
- `item_group` is the attribute on the `Item` object where the related `ItemGroup` is stored.
- `item_set` is the attribute on the `ItemGroup` object where the list of related `Item` objects should be stored.

Comment: Thanks, the generic flip stich looks fine so I will go with that. And I did mention, that my ItemGroup list is large. If I my queryset would contain only one ItemGroup , then prefetch would be ok. When I have many, only the length of the SQL alone is very large so I think it is not performant.

Comment: Unless you're running into database-level issues where the query is getting rejected for it being too large, the size of a query isn't inherently an issue. With the select_ query you're actually requesting more data to be piped over from the database.

Comment: I did notice a difference, the prefetch query is taking a little more then ~1 second, while the join take less then one second. Using django debug toolbar. Of course this is not a serious performance problem, but it did catch my eye, the difference is noticeable. Some of my queries requires two prefetch_related, which is even slower. And not a very large table, around 100K rows.

Comment: I'd look into what part of the query is taking so long to execute. You might have a hidden performance issue with how your models/tables are set up that you can correct. Or your network/disk/performance for your DB might have hidden issues. Definitely something to track down further, if you can, since it might come up again in the future.

Answer (score 8):

Using `prefetch_related` you will have two queries + the big IN clauses issue, although it is proven and portable.

I would give a solution that is more an example, based on your field names. It will create a function that transform from a serializer for `Item` using your `select_related` `queryset`. It will override the list function of the view and transform from one serializer data to the other one that will give you the representation you want. It will use only one query and parsing the results will be in `O(n)` so it should be fast.

You might need to refactor `get_data` in order to add more fields to your results.

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    group_name = serializers.CharField(source='item_group.group_name')

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ('item_name', 'group_name')

class ItemGSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    group_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
    items = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.CharField(max_length=50))
```

In the view:

```
class ItemGroupViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    model = models.Item
    serializer_class = serializers.ItemSerializer
    queryset = models.Item.objects.select_related('item_group').all()

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())

        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            data = self.get_data(serializer.data)
            s = serializers.ItemGSerializer(data, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(s.data)

        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        data = self.get_data(serializer.data)
        s = serializers.ItemGSerializer(data, many=True)
        return Response(s.data)

    @staticmethod
    def get_data(data):
        result, current_group = [], None
        for elem in data:
            if current_group is None:
                current_group = {'group_name': elem['group_name'], 'items': [elem['item_name']]}
            else:
                if elem['group_name'] == current_group['group_name']:
                    current_group['items'].append(elem['item_name'])
                else:
                    result.append(current_group)
                    current_group = {'group_name': elem['group_name'], 'items': [elem['item_name']]}

        if current_group is not None:
            result.append(current_group)
        return result
```

Here is my result with my fake data:

```
[{
    "group_name": "group #2",
    "items": [
        "first item",
        "2 item",
        "3 item"
    ]
},
{
    "group_name": "group #1",
    "items": [
        "g1 #1",
        "g1 #2",
        "g1 #3"
    ]
}]
```

Comment: Thanks, This does work but I don't like the manual assembly of the dictionary, this way it seems like you barely benefit anything from rest framework serializers. Is there any way to make it more generic? As I have number of use cases for this (queries with a slow prefetch_related)